# Does the entity model replace the model in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, entity-framework-4

Please forgive me if this is a stupid question but if I use the entity framework do I not need to create model classes manually? Does the entity model replace the need for the model?

Suggestions welcome to a complete newbie knob :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have up-voted this question because people ask me this a lot and I think there is an important interpretation of this design pattern to consider.

The model in MVC has a single purpose - to act as a bag of properties that must be passed between the controller and the view.

If you were to use an entity, instead of a specific model, would that entity contain everything you need? In most cases, the answer is no. You don't want to add a property to your entity to support something on a UI, so you should have a model that is specifically designed for that purpose.

I have often seen an entity as a property on the model though, which I don't have any problem with.

Comment: Thanks Sohnee, So lets say I have a table in sql called Order which contains OrderID,OrderDate,Shipped and then a 2nd table called OrderProducts which has the OrderID from the Order table and a foreign key ProductID.

Comment: Would I use themodel for both of these entites and map the properties I want against them e.g. Required=true displayname=blabla is that all what I would be using the model for? when I create the view what do I bind it to, the entity or the model?

Comment: @Diver Dan - create a **ViewModel** for the particular view. For instance if you want a View for creating an order, you might create a `OrderViewModel`, which contains a reference to an Order, and possibly a product, plus any other logic you require for the View. You then map between this ViewModel and your EDM - AutoMapper is good for this.

Comment: hey rpm do you know of any example source code out there that uses the viewmodel with the automapper?

Comment: Thanks RPM1984 - I agree with using Automapper for this. An alternative is to use "buddy classes" that extend the entity with these attributes, but I don't recommend that as it becomes hard to maintain.